# How can I change the column size for a specific column in a table

Tags: tables, pdftex

I want to change the `size` of a specific `column`. I check a lot of similar question on this website, it seems `\parbox[c]` and `\textwidth` are the command to adjust. I tried but fail to understand where to append this command based on my current codes. Can somebody tell me where can I adjust my codes to change the column width?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%

\begin{document}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
   \Xhline{0.9pt}
\makecell[lc]{Shrinkage\\ estimator} &\makecell{Prior} & \makecell{Posterior estimator} \\
\hline
Ridge &\(\beta_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}\Bigl(0,\mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)\)&\makecell{$\Bigl(1-\mfrac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\Bigr)\hat{\beta}_{i}, \lambda > 0$} \\
Lasso &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim \Laplace\Bigl(0, \mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)\)}&\makecell{$\sign\bigl(\hat{\beta}_i)(|\hat{\beta}_i| - \lambda\bigr)^+$} \\
James-Stein &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}(M, A)\)}&\makecell{$\Bigl(1-\mfrac{N-3}{\medop\sum_i^N(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})^2}\Bigr)^{\!+\!}\!(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})+\bar{\beta}$}
\\

Empirical Bayes &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim g_i(.)\)}&\makecell{ $\hat{\beta}_i+\sigma^2_{i}\frac{d}{d \hat{\beta_{i}}}\log \hat{m}(\hat{\beta}_i)$}
\\
\makecell[lc]{New empirical\\ Bayes}  &\makecell{\(\mathrm{p}_{i\pm}\sim g_{i\pm}(.)\)}& \makecell[lc]{ \psi(1+z_{i+}) - \psi(1-z_{i+}+n_{i+}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z_{i+}}\mathrm{log}m_{+}(z_{i+})
\\ - \psi(1+z_{i-}) - \psi(1-z_{i-}+n_{i-}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z_{i-}}\mathrm{log}m_{-}(z_{i-})}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
 \label{tab3}
 \caption{Summary of shrinkage estimators. The parametric Bayes estimators ridge, lasso, James-Stein estimator. The ridge and James-Stein estimator specify a normal prior while the lasso specify a Laplace prior. The empirical Bayes estimator and the assumption-free empirical Bayes estimator do not specify any prior.} \label{notaion}
\hfill \break

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code produces several errors, please fix your MWE.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for reminding me. I just re-edited.

Comment: I still get an error. Undefined control sequence `\mcell@MB@`. Also undefined control sequence `\mfrac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different widths for `X` columns. I also loaded the `geometry` package, to have more sensible margins if you don't use marginal notes, and simplified your code for the formulae. In particular, the `esdiff` package eases typing (partial or not) derivatives, and `nccmath` has commands for medium-sized formulae (about 80 % of `\displaystyle`).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{nccmath, esdiff}
\newcommand\mdiffp[2]{\medmath{\diffp{#1}{{#2}}}}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, caption}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Laplace}{Laplace}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%
  \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|>{\hsize=0.65\hsize\centering\arraybackslash$}X<{$}|>{\hsize=1.35\hsize\centering\arraybackslash$}X <{$}@{}}
    \Xhline{0.9pt}
    \makecell[lc]{Shrinkage \\ estimator} &\text{Prior} & \text{Posterior estimator} \\
    \hline
    Ridge & \beta_{i} ∼ \mathcal{N}\Bigl(0,\mfrac{1}{λ}\Bigr) & \makecell{ \Bigl(1-\mfrac{λ}{1+λ}\Bigr)\hat{β}_{i}, λ> 0 } \\
    Lasso & \makecell{\beta_{i} ∼ \Laplace\Bigl(0, \mfrac{1}{λ}\Bigr)} & \makecell{ \sign\bigl(\hat{β}_i)(|\hat{β}_i| - λ\bigr)^+} \\
    James-Stein & \makecell{\beta_{i} ∼ \mathcal{N}(M, A)} & \makecell{\Bigl(1-\mfrac{N-3}{\medop∑_i^N(\hat{β}_{i}-\bar{β})²}\Bigr)^{\!+\!}\!(\hat{β}_{i}-\bar{β})+\bar{β}}
    \\

    Empirical Bayes & \makecell{\beta_{i} ∼ g_i( · )} & \makecell{\hat{β}_i+\sigma²_{i}\diff{}{\hat{\beta_{i}}}\log \hat{m}(\hat{β}_i)}
    \\
    \makecell[lc]{New empirical \\ Bayes} &\makecell{\mathrm{p}_{i±} ∼ g_{i±}( · )}& \begin{aligned} & ψ(1+z_{i+}) - ψ(1-z_{i+}+n_{i+}) + \mdiffp{}{z_{i+}}\log m_{+}(z_{i+})
      \\[-0.5ex] & -ψ(1+z_{i-}) - ψ(1-z_{i-}+n_{i-}) + \mdiffp{}{z_{i-}}\log m_{-}(z_{i-})\end{aligned}
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab3}
  \caption{Summary of shrinkage estimators. The parametric Bayes estimators ridge, lasso, James-Stein estimator. The ridge and James-Stein estimator specify a normal prior while the lasso specify a Laplace prior. The empirical Bayes estimator and the assumption-free empirical Bayes estimator do not specify any prior.} \label{notaion}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have (to) many errors in your *mwe*, from missing packages in preamble, missing own definitions for new commands to not declared math operators. also typesetting of math expressions is unusual and make troubles to understanding, what actually you like to express (consequently some my correction can be wrong due to misunderstanding)

for make different width of `X` columns you can find in `tabularx` documentation:

```
>{\hsize=x\hsize}X
```

where `x` is number express relative change of column width (for details see package documentation. however this changes is not sufficient to put last math expression in two line cell. it is necessary to break it at least in three lines (see *mwe* below).

one of major cause, that your *mwe* doesn't work is use macro `makegapedcell` from package `makecell`. instead it i suggest to use `cellspace` macro and defined `\cellspacetoplimit{...}` and `\cellspacebottomlimit{...}`. for their activation in table the column specifier `S` had to be add to used column type in columns with the most critical vertical spacing (see *mwe* below).

after cleaning of your mwe and adding all missing packages, commands, declarations, environments and some reorganization of code your *mwe* become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}   % added
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign} % added

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{cellspace,            % added
            makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}  % added
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}                 % added
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}              % added

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]                             % added
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Sl|              % changed
    >{\hsize=0.4\hsize $\displaystyle}C<{$}|
    >{\hsize=0.6\hsize $\displaystyle}SC<{$}
                             @{} }
   \Xhline{0.9pt}
\makecell[l]{Shrinkage\\ estimator}
    &   \makecell{\text{Prior}}                   % changed
        &   \makecell{\text{Posterior estimator}} % changed                          \\
\hline
Ridge
    &   \beta_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}\Bigl(0,\mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)
        &   \Bigl(1-\mfrac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\Bigr)\hat{\beta}_{i},\lambda>0   \\
Lasso
    &   \beta_{i}\sim \mathcal{L}\Bigl(0, \mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)
        &   \sign\bigl(\hat{\beta}_i)(|\hat{\beta}_i| - \lambda\bigr)^+         \\
James-Stein
    &   \beta_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}(M, A)
        &   \Bigl(1-\mfrac{N-3}{\sum_i^N(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})^2}
            \Bigr)^{+}\!(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})+\bar{\beta}               \\
Empirical Bayes
    &   \beta_{i}\sim g_i(.)
        &   \hat{\beta}_i+\sigma^2_{i}
            \mfrac{d}{d \hat{\beta_{i}}}\log \hat{m}(\hat{\beta}_i)              \\
\makecell[l]{New empirical\\ Bayes}
    &   \mathrm{p}_{i\pm}\sim g_{i\pm}(.)
        &   \begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth]
            \psi(1+z_{i+}) - \psi(1-z_{i+}+n_{i+}) \\
            + \mfrac{\partial}{\partial z_{i+}}\log m_{+}(z_{i+}) -
                                    \psi(1+z_{i-})      \\
            - \psi(1-z_{i-}+n_{i-}) +
            \mfrac{\partial}{\partial z_{i-}}\log m_{-}(z_{i-})
            \end{multlined}                                                     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Summary of shrinkage estimators. The parametric Bayes estimators ridge, lasso, James-Stein estimator. The ridge and James-Stein estimator specify a normal prior while the lasso specify a Laplace prior. The empirical Bayes estimator and the assumption-free empirical Bayes estimator do not specify any prior.}
\label{notaion}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]